# Do entry components need selectors in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Do entry components (those components which are loaded imperatively by the router and never declaratively by their selectors) need selectors?

For example:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'app-example', // <-- is this needed?
    // ...
)
export class ExampleComponent {}
```

Comment: It isn't but it is a good practice to do so IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** In angualr, A selector is not always needed, In this case you have a top component of a module that is loaded by router and displayed.

This **[`feature`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1662)** is supported, and you can refer it in the **[`docs`](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-an-entry-component)**

Answer (score 1):

> No It's not required to provide selector

Here is the working example of routes without selector :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routes-noname

---

**Reason for selector :**

Angular2 / + is fully component based, reason behind the selector is just modularity, so you can use the same component at multiple places.

But if the component will not be used anywhere except the routes, it will work.